# SQL-Server, TSQL, TRY-CATCH block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a problem with try/catch error-handling.
Let's have a look on my (simple) code:

```
BEGIN TRY
print 'important'
use myDB1; -- no problem, the myDB1 is in place...
select * from dbo.Tab1;
use myDB2;
--here error, the myDB2 is not there, 
--but error handling doesn't jump into catch-block

select * from dbo.Tab2;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    print 'myDB2 is not there'
END CATCH
```

I know, I could say:

`select * from myDB2.dbo.Tab2` without changing to myDB2, but when I need to check (for example..) if a table has an identity

```
(((SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('myDB2.dbo.'+ @TableName), 'TableHasIdentity'))= 1)
```

I must run this from myDB2, otherwise I'll get a wrong result.
So how can I catch the error in the catch-block?

Thanks for your help

Purclot

Comment: Has you tried to to use full qualified names instead of changing DB context, like select * from myDB2.dbo.Tab2?

Comment: BTW, if you want to check if a Database and object exists why not select from sys.sysdatabases and sys.sysobjects?

Comment: hi Jean,
as I said: I need to change into the database (so it's not a solution using: select * from myDB2.dbo.Tab2...).
When I use: if(exists(select 1 from master.dbo.sysdatabase where [name] = 'myDB2') use myDB2, I'll get an errror anyway.

Comment: just try select * from sys.sysdatabases from any database context, trying to access master database can fail if you don't got the right permissions. Also the point is why do you need to change the database context? You can access any object from any database if you got the right permissions for both databases.

Comment: hi Jean,as I've told above:
I know, I could say: 

select * from myDB2.dbo.Tab2 without changing to myDB2, but when I need to check (for example..) if a table has an identity 

(((SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('myDB2.dbo.'+ @TableName), 'TableHasIdentity'))= 1)I must run this from myDB2, otherwise I'll get a wrong result.

Comment: @Purclot: this is a difficult scenario to handle.  I'm not sure I can directly answer your question.  But there are some workarounds.  You can iterate through the db's from master and call sp_executesql.  If you must be in the context of the db, then you'd pass a dynamically created tsql string.  Something like sp_executesql (N'dbname.sp_executesql (<sql command to run on dbname>)').  It's a little convoluted, but doable.  Here's an example that demonstrates [link]http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1545082-2799-1.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encapsulate the test condition in an EXEC to get the error to be treated as a run-time issue. You then need to fully-qualify the objects for the queries that hit databases that might not exist so that you can avoid the USE statement. For functions such as OBJECTPROPERTY that require local context, you can use sp_executesql to run queries in a different database context and return a usable result.

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME,
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Result BIT

BEGIN TRY

    USE [master];
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects

    SET @TableName = N'sysjobhistory'
    SET @Result = 0
    SET @SQL = N'USE [msdb]; DECLARE @Result BIT;
                 SET @TempResult = OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(N''' + @TableName +
                 N'''), ''TableHasIdentity'')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                       N'@TempResult BIT OUTPUT',
                       @TempResult = @Result OUTPUT

    SELECT @Result AS [ResultThatCanBeUsedLocally]

    EXEC('USE [NotHere];')

    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM NotHere.sys.objects

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    PRINT 'Error!!'
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

After some chatty comments OP just needs to know if table got a identity.
You can use it to list tables without identity in a given database

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM MyDB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_NAME NOT IN (
    SELECT c.TABLE_NAME
    FROM MyDB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    INNER JOIN MyDB2.sys.identity_columns ic ON c.COLUMN_NAME = ic.NAME
)
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

**EDIT**

after some more chat and digging I found OP really wants to switch DB inside a try catch block. But that object existence is checked at parse time and a try catch ill work only on run time errors.
Also object missing errors appear to not get the necessary severity to be caught by the try catch block (and even using a full qualified name ill not to work)

OP must rethink how he can accomplish the task.

Comment: Hi Jean,
I'm afraid we're just drifting away from the merit of the main problem:
how to get the catch-block working when I just want to swich to a database that doesn't exist - for what reason ever. The issue with the HasIdentity-property was just an example.
Purclot

Comment: Sorry, my point was to avoid switching context inside a try catch. At first I cannot find anything about that specific scenario. If you really want to go with it let's dig a bit more

Comment: I guess I found the problem. When I try to parse your code it raises a error. That means the DB non existence ill be handled at parse time, not runtime where the try catch lives.