# How to maintain Error Log if Stored Procedure throws an Error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We have a scenario where if a Stored Procedure throws Error, then we need to record Error related data, Parameters, and Time when the Stored Procedure throw Error into an Error Log table in TRY CATCH Block. Can any one please help?

Comment: I would suggest reffering to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194198/sql-server-tsql-try-catch-block, Or you can refer to microsoft's documentation to get all needed parameters on what the catch block provides.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table for logging the error details something like this.....

```
CREATE TABLE Error_Log 
(
  ProcName      SYSNAME
 ,LoggedAt      DATETIME
 ,ErrorMessage  NVARCHAR(4000)
 ,ErrorLine     NVARCHAR(4000)
 ,ErrorNumber   INT
 ,ErrorSeverity INT
 ,ErrorState    INT
 ,ParamDetails  NVARCHAR(MAX) 
)
GO
```

Then you logging error details yes you are correct `TRY & CATCH` blocks is what you need something like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myTestProc
  @Var1 INT 
 ,@Var2 INT
 ,@Var3 VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY


  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    /* Do your stuff here*/
    /* if Every thing goes fine commit transaction*/
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   /* else the contorl will jump to catch block*/
END TRY



BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --<-- If any open trans rollback

  /* Now here log error details */

  DECLARE @ParamDetails NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @ParamDetails = ' @Var1 = ' + CAST(ISNULL(@Var1, 'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                    + ',@Var2 = ' + CAST(ISNULL(@Var2, 'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                    + ',@Var3 = ' + CAST(ISNULL(@Var3, 'NULL') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

  INSERT INTO Error_Log (ProcName , LoggedAt , ErrorMessage , ErrorLine 
                          ,ErrorNumber ,ErrorSeverity, ErrorState , ParamDetails)
  VALUES (ERROR_PROCEDURE() , GETDATE() , ERROR_MESSAGE() , ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_NUMBER() 
        , ERROR_SEVERITY() , ERROR_STATE(), @ParamDetails)

END CATCH

END
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this as follows :-

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_XYZ_Insert_Update]
     @Param1            Int
    ,@Param2            Date
    ,@Username          Varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare  @Error Int = 0

    Insert Into XYZTable(Col1, Col2)
    Values(@Param1,@Param2)

    Set @Error = @@Error
    If (@Error <> 0) Goto Error

    Goto EndProc

Error:
Begin
    Insert Into ErrorLog(ProcedureName,SPParameters,LogDatetime,UserName,ErrorCode)
    Select   'USP_XYZ_Insert_Update'
            ,'Param1 =' + Cast(@Param1 As Varchar(10)) + '; Param2 = ' + Cast(@Param2 As Varchar(10)) + ';'
            ,Getdate()
            ,@Username
            ,@Error
End

EndProc:

END
GO
```

Comment: Mihir what you have done, it will work but it is pretty ancient :) using try and catch block will have a lot more robust code will handle code a lot more elegantly. Your method looks ok for this specific example you have provided but if you were executing more than one statement in in proc you will need to capture value of `@@ERROR` after each statement which is a bit of pain considering some procs can have a lot more than just 1 statement etc.

Comment: Might be, i don't know which one is best practice for handling error in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following code:
The ErrorLog Table

```
    CREATE TABLE [ErrorLog]
    (
        ErrorMessage    NVARCHAR(512)
    ,   ErrorSeverity   INT
    ,   ErrorNumber     INT
    ,   ErrorState      INT
    ,   ErrorProcedure  SYSNAME
    ,   ProcParameters  VARCHAR(50)
    ,   ErrorLine       INT
    ,   ErrorTime       DATETIME
    )
```

The Procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [DivideByZero]
    (
        @First  INT
    ,   @Last   INT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SELECT  (@First / @Last)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
                SELECT  ERROR_MESSAGE()
                    ,   ERROR_SEVERITY()
                    ,   ERROR_NUMBER()
                    ,   ERROR_STATE()
                    ,   ERROR_PROCEDURE()
                    ,   CONVERT(VARCHAR, @First) + ',' + 
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Last)
                    ,   ERROR_LINE()    
                    ,   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        END CATCH
    END
```

Execute the procedure to create an error

```
    EXEC [DivideByZero] 1, 0
```

Select from the error log table

```
    SELECT * FROM ErrorLog
```

You should get the following output:

```
    ErrorMessage                        ErrorSeverity   ErrorNumber ErrorState  ErrorProcedure  ProcParameters  ErrorLine   ErrorTime
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Divide by zero error encountered.   16              8134        1           DivideByZero    1,0             10          2011-09-11 15:15:10.803
```

Comment: I think, `INSERT statement` is missing in your catch block.